# Having trouble with my nav bar/header, It used to work but now it doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating this website for a company for my student co-op and I had this header made for my website and when I made it, it worked completely fine. Now when I check on my phone I press the services button for my dropdown menu and it doesn't come down, but when I try on the google chrome dev responsive tool, I can click the drop down menu but I also cant unclick the menu. I understand that I have a lot of code written in my CSS file, I do have stuff labeled though like header/home page.

My Issue:

When I click on my responsive navbar when it's resized to a smaller ratio. I click the bar and my nav menu pulls up but when I click on my services drop down menu It doesn't come down, Although it works on google chrome responsive dev tools. But when I click the services button and it works the dropdown wont go away when I click it again, how can I fix this? Majority of my navbar is labeled "Header" in my css file. I decided to put my whole file in as maybe something is over writing it but I have no clue it is?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Meta Data *IGNORE* !-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css1/headerNewCSS.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Header !-->
    <header>
        <div style="background-color: #1E90FF;" class="container-fluid">
            <nav>
                <div class="menu-icons">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="index.php" class="logo">
                    <img class="logo" src="images/logo_trans.png" alt="logo" style="height: 75px;">
                </a>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <!-- Normal listing buttons !-->
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown">Services
                            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <!-- Drop Down List !-->
                        <ul id="drop-sub" class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="businessPrintingPage1.php">Business Printing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="canvasPrintingPage1.php">Canvas Printing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="embroideryPage1.php">Embroidery</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="engravingPage1.php">Engraving</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="signsPage1.php">Signs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="apperalPage1.php">Custom Apperal</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Normal listing buttons !-->
                    <li>
                        <a href="Promotions.php">Promotions</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="partners.php">Partners</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="aboutUs.php">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="contactUs.php">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    
                    <!-- Cart !-->
                    <li class="move-right">
                        <img class="cart" style="float: right;" src="images/new_cart.png" alt="Cart">
                    </li>
                    
                
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Javascript for making a new navbar image for responsiveness !-->
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
/* DONT TOUCH ANY OF THESE INFORMATION */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* END OF UNTOUCHABLE INFORMATION */

/*-------------------------------------------- STYLING FOR HEADER ----------------------------------------------*/
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 117rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
  display: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
  line-height: 8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 650ms;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cart {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1.3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  border: 2px solid #1e90ff;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 20rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 3px solid #00bfff;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 16rem;
  transition: all 650ms ease;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5rem;
  left: 3rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
  top: 0.9rem;
  left: -2.5rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 3px solid #00bfff;
  top: 0;
  left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 8rem;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

li.move-right {
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
  line-height: initial;
  transition: color 650ms;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}
/*-------------------------------------------- STYLING FOR HEADER END ----------------------------------------------*/

/*-------------------------------------------- RESPONSIVENESS FOR HEADER ----------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-list {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    align-items: initial;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1e90ff;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .nav-list li {
    line-height: 6rem;
  }

  .sub-menu {
    position: initial;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #00bfff;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    max-height: 0;
     display: none;
  }

  .sub-menu::before {
    display: none;
  }

    .nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
    
    .sub-menu-vis {
    opacity: 1;
     display: block;
    visibility: visible !important;
    max-height: initial;
  }

  li.move-right {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
    line-height: initial;
  }

  .menu-icons {
    display: block;
  }

  .fas fa-times {
    display: none;
  }
    
  .dropdown{
     cursor: pointer; 
  }

  nav.active .fas fa-times {
    display: block;
  }

  nav.active .fas fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }

  nav.active .nav-list {
    display: flex;
  }
}
/*-------------------------------------------- RESPONSIVENESS FOR HEADER END ----------------------------------------------*/

/* ----------------------------- STYLING FOR TABLE -------------------------------------- */
/* Table container */
.tableContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;;
}

/* Contents of the table that are being style */
.tableContents {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.tableContents table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tableContents th {
    background-color: #1e90ff;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.tableContents td {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}



.tableContents tr {
    background-color: #F0F8FF;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 15px;
    
}

.tableContents tr:hover {
    background-color: white;

}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}


/* Fixing margins for phone */
.tablePhoneFix {
        margin-left: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

/* ----------------------------- STYLING FOR TABLE END -------------------------------------- */











/* ----------------------------- STYLING FOR HERO IMAGE BANNER -------------------------------------- */
.back-test {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* ----------------------------- STYLING FOR HERO IMAGE BANNER END -------------------------------------- */











/*------------------------------------------- TABLE RESPONSIVENESS ----------------------------------------------*/
@media (max-width: 730px) {
    .tableContainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 90%;
    }
    
    .tableContents {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-left: 10px;
}

    .tableContents th {
        background-color: #1e90ff;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        font-size: 20px;
}


    .tableContents tr {
        background-color: #F0F8FF;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
        font-size: 15px;
    
}
    .tablePhoneFix {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .back-test {
        height: 200vh;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

}
/*------------------------------------------- TABLE RESPONSIVENESS END ----------------------------------------------*/
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const selectElement = (element) => document.querySelector(element);

selectElement('.menu-icons').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement('nav').classList.toggle('active');
    });
        
var drop = document.querySelector(".dropdown");     
drop.addEventListener("click", function() {
var sub = document.querySelector("#drop-sub");  
    if(sub.classList.contains("sub-menu-vis")){
        document.getElementById("drop-sub").classList.remove("sub-menu-vis");
        }else{
        document.getElementById("drop-sub").classList.add("sub-menu-vis");
    }
});
```

Comment: Your hover attribute does not work on phones because it is touch screen you have to make a click.

Comment: The thing is, it was working, you just had to click it and it'd start hovering but now it's not working

Comment: But on mobile devices there is no way to unhover. Look what I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done:
This is a link because there was to much code to put in the snippet.
https://jsfiddle.net/Allan_StackoverFlow/stygwvx7/3/

Javascript:

```
(function() {
        const selectElement = (element) => document.querySelector(element);

selectElement('.menu-icons').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement('nav').classList.toggle('active');
    });
        
var drop = document.querySelector(".dropdown");     
drop.addEventListener("click", function() {
var sub = document.querySelector("#drop-sub");  
    if(sub.classList.contains("sub-menu-vis")){
        document.getElementById("drop-sub").classList.remove("sub-menu-vis");
        }else{
        document.getElementById("drop-sub").classList.add("sub-menu-vis");
    }
});

})();
```

There is only room for the javascript. The html and css were edited.

You can get the code from there.

Try This!

UPDATE:
The CSS I updated

```
/*-------------------------------------------- RESPONSIVENESS FOR HEADER ----------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-list {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    align-items: initial;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1e90ff;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .nav-list li {
    line-height: 6rem;
  }

  .sub-menu {
    position: initial;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #00bfff;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    max-height: 0;
     display: none;
  }

  .sub-menu::before {
    display: none;
  }

    .nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
    
    .sub-menu-vis {
    opacity: 1;
     display: block;
    visibility: visible !important;
    max-height: initial;
  }

  li.move-right {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
    line-height: initial;
  }

  .menu-icons {
    display: block;
  }

  .fas fa-times {
    display: none;
  }
    
  .dropdown{
     cursor: pointer; 
  }

  nav.active .fas fa-times {
    display: block;
  }

  nav.active .fas fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }

  nav.active .nav-list {
    display: flex;
  }
}
/*-------------------------------------------- RESPONSIVENESS FOR HEADER END ----------------------------------------------*/
```

```js
    const selectElement = (element) => document.querySelector(element);

selectElement('.menu-icons').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement('nav').classList.toggle('active');
    });
        
var drop = document.querySelector(".dropdown");     
drop.addEventListener("click", function() {
var sub = document.querySelector("#drop-sub");  
    if(sub.classList.contains("sub-menu-vis")){
        document.getElementById("drop-sub").classList.remove("sub-menu-vis");
        }else{
        document.getElementById("drop-sub").classList.add("sub-menu-vis");
    }
});
```

```css
/* DONT TOUCH ANY OF THESE INFORMATION */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* END OF UNTOUCHABLE INFORMATION */

/*-------------------------------------------- STYLING FOR HEADER ----------------------------------------------*/
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 117rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1500;
  display: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
  line-height: 8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 650ms;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cart {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1.3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  border: 2px solid #1e90ff;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 20rem;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 3px solid #00bfff;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 16rem;
  transition: all 650ms ease;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5rem;
  left: 3rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
  top: 0.9rem;
  left: -2.5rem;
  border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #00bfff;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 3px solid #00bfff;
  top: 0;
  left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 8rem;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

li.move-right {
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
  line-height: initial;
  transition: color 650ms;
  transition: background-color 650ms;
}
/*-------------------------------------------- STYLING FOR HEADER END ----------------------------------------------*/

/*-------------------------------------------- RESPONSIVENESS FOR HEADER ----------------------------------------------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-list {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    align-items: initial;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1e90ff;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  .nav-list li {
    line-height: 6rem;
  }

  .sub-menu {
    position: initial;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #00bfff;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    max-height: 0;
     display: none;
  }

  .sub-menu::before {
    display: none;
  }

    .nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
    
    .sub-menu-vis {
    opacity: 1;
     display: block;
    visibility: visible !important;
    max-height: initial;
  }

  li.move-right {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
    line-height: initial;
  }

  .menu-icons {
    display: block;
  }

  .fas fa-times {
    display: none;
  }
    
  .dropdown{
     cursor: pointer; 
  }

  nav.active .fas fa-times {
    display: block;
  }

  nav.active .fas fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }

  nav.active .nav-list {
    display: flex;
  }
}
/*-------------------------------------------- RESPONSIVENESS FOR HEADER END ----------------------------------------------*/

/* ----------------------------- STYLING FOR TABLE -------------------------------------- */
/* Table container */
.tableContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;;
}

/* Contents of the table that are being style */
.tableContents {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.tableContents table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tableContents th {
    background-color: #1e90ff;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.tableContents td {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}



.tableContents tr {
    background-color: #F0F8FF;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 15px;
    
}

.tableContents tr:hover {
    background-color: white;

}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}


/* Fixing margins for phone */
.tablePhoneFix {
        margin-left: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

/* ----------------------------- STYLING FOR TABLE END -------------------------------------- */











/* ----------------------------- STYLING FOR HERO IMAGE BANNER -------------------------------------- */
.back-test {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* ----------------------------- STYLING FOR HERO IMAGE BANNER END -------------------------------------- */











/*------------------------------------------- TABLE RESPONSIVENESS ----------------------------------------------*/
@media (max-width: 730px) {
    .tableContainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 90%;
    }
    
    .tableContents {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-left: 10px;
}

    .tableContents th {
        background-color: #1e90ff;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        font-size: 20px;
}


    .tableContents tr {
        background-color: #F0F8FF;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
        font-size: 15px;
    
}
    .tablePhoneFix {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .back-test {
        height: 200vh;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

}
/*------------------------------------------- TABLE RESPONSIVENESS END ----------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Meta Data *IGNORE* !-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css1/styler.css">
    <script src="javascript/script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Header !-->
    <header>
        <div style="background-color: #1E90FF;" class="container-fluid">
            <nav>
                <div class="menu-icons">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="index.php" class="logo">
                    <img class="logo" src="images/logo_trans.png" alt="logo" style="height: 75px;">
                </a>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <!-- Normal listing buttons !-->
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown">Services
                            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <!-- Drop Down List !-->
                        <ul id="drop-sub" class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="businessPrintingPage1.php">Business Printing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="canvasPrintingPage1.php">Canvas Printing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="embroideryPage1.php">Embroidery</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="engravingPage1.php">Engraving</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="signsPage1.php">Signs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="apperalPage1.php">Custom Apperal</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Normal listing buttons !-->
                    <li>
                        <a href="Promotions.php">Promotions</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="partners.php">Partners</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="aboutUs.php">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="contactUs.php">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    
                    <!-- Cart !-->
                    <li class="move-right">
                        <img class="cart" style="float: right;" src="images/new_cart.png" alt="Cart">
                    </li>
                    
                
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Javascript for making a new navbar image for responsiveness !-->
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Did you only change the javascript here?

Comment: No I changed the CSS AND HTML be there was not room to put it in the post. Look here for full code: https://jsfiddle.net/Allan_StackoverFlow/stygwvx7/3/

Comment: It should work now on mobile devices. It will be a tap on tap off.

Comment: What parts of the CSS and HTML did you change? I took the Header HTML code and CSS HEADER code but not getting luck with it, the sub menu doesnt even come out now

Comment: You have to click on It now

Comment: Yeah I tried clicking on it and It wasn't coming out

Comment: Go here: https://allancoding.000webhostapp.com/stackoverflow/Having-trouble-with-my-nav-bar-header-It-used-to-work-but-now-it-doesn't.html

Comment: Im just curious on what parts of the css you've changed because I did a switch on my CSS stylesheet, and made seperate style sheets for each page so I didn't have over 2000+ lines

Comment: The RESPONSIVENESS FOR HEADER part. Did it work for you? I updated my post look above!

Comment: So I switched it all up and tried it and when I do hover or click on it, the yellow does come up but for some reason the sub menu does not drop down, and still for some reason when I try it on my phone there is so background color change either

Comment: Try this url for testing in case it is some other code: https://allancoding.000webhostapp.com/stackoverflow/Having-trouble-with-my-nav-bar-header-It-used-to-work-but-now-it-doesn't.html

Comment: Yes I tried that on my phone and it works how i'd want it, but for some reason it's not working on my main code

Comment: Do you have your website url that I can look at for testing?

Comment: I have no idea If I can give that to you cause it's a companies URL but maybe we can figure something out in DMs?

Comment: So it is your css in the main page that is making it not work.

Comment: Why can't you give me the company's url you could delete the comment after I see it.

Comment: I'm going to update on how my header looks now and my header css file, I'll update it on the main post, I cant see how my other CSS files will stop it cause its like seperate .css sheets

Comment: They can interact with each other if they are affecting the same element.

Comment: Just edited my main post maybe that could help?

Comment: In the snippet above everything is right it could be some img problem?

Comment: I have no idea, what could the img problem be doing? Anything I should look for?

Comment: If I could see the main page I could help you alot. So try to put the full main page in a JsFiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o94stfu7/ I don't think I did it right but the HTML code for my main page is in there but I couldn't figure out a way to put my Header in there too

Comment: Yeah I did, unless for some reason it's not uploading properly. I opened my header file on firefox on my folder on my desktop and it worked, so I have no clue if it uploaded correctly or not

Comment: Look Here: https://allancoding.000webhostapp.com/stackoverflow/Having-trouble-with-my-nav-bar-header-It-used-to-work-but-now-it-doesn't.php

Comment: I just checked, I think it's not compatiable with google chrome or safari or something but it works on fire fox

Comment: It is working in chrome on mobile and desktop.

Comment: Could you also give me the images.

Comment: Holy cow, so I go onto my website on firefox and it seems to work, I go on google chrome and it doesn't work and it dont work on safari, but for some reason It works on chrome and my phone with your website, WHAT IS GOING ON?!!?!

Comment: At this point I don't think it's the images, firefox it works fine for me with my website but chrome doesnt but with your website all works

Comment: Try a Force a cache reload.

Comment: For some reason I cant even click it on my phone on my website, it doesnt even hover yellow

Comment: With mine or yours?

Comment: **Windows:** ctrl + F5
**Mac/Apple:** Apple + R or command + R
**Linux:** F5

Comment: You could replace me website with yours?

Comment: Omg okay so I reset my cache and it finally seems like it's working, I appreciate it so much and thank you for the help

Comment: Try This as your javascript`(function() {
const selectElement = (element) => document.querySelector(element);
selectElement('.menu-icons').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement('nav').classList.toggle('active');
    });
  
var drop = document.querySelector(".dropdown");  
drop.addEventListener("click", function() {
var sub = document.querySelector("#drop-sub"); 
 if(sub.classList.contains("sub-menu-vis")){
  document.getElementById("drop-sub").classList.remove("sub-menu-vis");
  }else{
  document.getElementById("drop-sub").classList.add("sub-menu-vis");
 }
});})();`

Comment: Was this what is was doing? https://jsfiddle.net/Allan_StackoverFlow/qtx62ua4/2/